# Django inspectdb on fails on table's foreign key which refs a table outside the current database (MySQL 5.0)

Tags: python, django, django-orm

I tested with Python 2.6 or 2.7 with Django 1.5.1. My database is on MySQL 5.0. I've created the settings but now I can't run "inspectdb" on the database. I get

> DatabaseError: (1146, "Table 'db1.tableName' doesn't exist")

This happens on a table which has a foreign key referencing a table in another DB. So it should not be db1 there since tableName lives in db2. I saw references to this bug from 5 years ago:

https://code.djangoproject.com/ticket/7556

But the patch is outdated by now and I figured it must have been finished in a later release. Is it something wrong with my setup?

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, Django still does not currently [does not support this feature](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev//topics/db/multi-db/#limitations-of-multiple-databases).

> Cross-database relations:
>
> Django doesn’t currently provide any support for foreign key or
>   many-to-many relationships spanning multiple databases. If you have
>   used a router to partition models to different databases, any foreign
>   key and many-to-many relationships defined by those models must be
>   internal to a single database.

However, a fix could be found on this patch [here](https://code.djangoproject.com/attachment/ticket/17875/foreignkey-db-using.patch)

Basically, updating the router settings `self.rel.to`